# Number of virtual cores + how to know the right value

Tags: linux, redhat, central-processing-unit, top, multi-core

from lscpu we get the following

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                48
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-47
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    12
Socket(s):             2
```

dose output from lscpu means that we have:

```
Number of virtual cores - ( 2 X 2 X 48 = 192 )
```

OR

```
Number of virtual cores - ( 2 X 48 = 96 )
```

OR

```
Number of virtual cores - ( 48 )
```

what is the right answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following:

- 48 threads (or vCPU);
- 2 threads per "real" core, so 24 "real" CPU cores;
- 2 sockets, each with a 12 core and 2 threads per core (so 24 threads total) per CPU socket.

In other words, imagine having two 12-cores Xeon or EPYC CPU.